# Make folder visible to user but do not allow them to access its contents (icacls)

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

I have the following file structure:

```
Parent Folder
  Folder A
   Folder B
   File A
```

So, `Folder A` is a sub-directory of `Parent Folder`, and `Folder B` and `File A` are sub-contents of `Folder A`.

I would want a particular set of users where `Folder A` is visible to them, but prevent them from accessing its contents (`Folder B` and `File A`)

How would I set that up with icacls?

Comment: Is "access-based enumeration"  enabled on your system? What happens if you literally /grant the read permissions?

Comment: @user1686 sorry for the delay in response. Been experimenting tirelessly on it. I have found another interesting behavior regarding this and asked an alternative question titled "Different behaviors for restricted access of folders in local drive and network shared drive". Could it really be because of "access-based enumeration" for network shared drives causing it?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use to be able to open **Parent Folder** and see **Folder A** listed in there, but not be able to open ***Folder A*** (hence not be able to see *Folder B* and *File A* listed there)?

Isn't that the default bahviour of `icacls` if you don't specify the `/T` switch (that indicates that this operation is performed on all matching files/directories below the directories specified)?

```
icacls "Parent Folder/Folder A" /grant YourUser:F
```

Comment: Hi Yisroel Tech. I tried doing that but the user is still able to access the contents of Folder A. I also tried using `icacls "Parent Folder/Folder A" /grant YourUser:(R)`, but he still is able to see the contents.

Comment: Weird, I tried removing the user on `Parent Folder/Folder A` and still give full read permissions (which includes listing of contents) to `Parent Folder` on both my local computer and on network drive. It seems to work on my local computer, but not on the network drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have researched online on "access-based enumeration" and indeed checking it will not allow restricted users to see the folder at all. [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TzHP00Vxi0) to see how it works.

Credit to @user1686 for pointing it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).